# Retrieve data into ajax drop-down menu using PHP MySql JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I created dynamic multiple country dropdown using `Jquery/PHP/MySql`. this worked fine and i `store/put` country/state/town for each user in MySql Database like this `(usertable)` :

```
id  |  country  | state | town |
 1  |     1     |   1   |   1  |
 2  |     1     |   1   |   3  |
 3  |     1     |   2   |   8  |
```

now in `edituser.php` page I need to `fetch/retrieve` MySql data `(usertable)` to my Jquery/Ajax dropdown. i call `edituser.php?id=1` Now I need to print/show user data to `dropdown Ajax` for edit country/state/town user.

How can I **retrieve/print/show** this?

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
// jquery library file
<script type="text/javascript">

/*This function is called when state dropdown value change*/
function selectState(state_id){
  if(state_id!="-1"){
    loadData('city',state_id);
  }else{
    $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select city</option>");
  }
}

/*This function is called when city dropdown value change*/
function selectCity(country_id){
 if(country_id!="-1"){
   loadData('state',country_id);
   $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select city</option>");
 }else{
  $("#state_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select state</option>");
   $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select city</option>");
 }
}

/*This is the main content load function, and it will
     called whenever any valid dropdown value changed.*/
function loadData(loadType,loadId){
  var dataString = 'loadType='+ loadType +'&loadId='+ loadId;
  $("#"+loadType+"_loader").show();
  $("#"+loadType+"_loader").fadeIn(400).
        html('Please wait... <img src="image/loading.gif" />');
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "loadData.php",
     data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     success: function(result){
       $("#"+loadType+"_loader").hide();
       $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").
       html("<option value='-1'>Select "+loadType+"</option>");
       $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").append(result);
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
/*This code will show country dropdown list*/
<select onchange="selectCity(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
   <option value="-1">Select country</option>
   <?php
     while($rowCountry=mysql_fetch_array($resCountry)){
   ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $rowCountry['id']?>">
            <?php echo $rowCountry['country_name']?>
     </option>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
</select>

/*State dropdown list*/
<select id="state_dropdown"
     onchange="selectState(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="-1">Select state</option>
</select>
<span id="state_loader"></span>

/*City dropdown list*/
<select id="city_dropdown">
<option value="-1">Select city</option>
</select>
<span id="city_loader"></span>
```

Loaddata.php

```
include('dbConnect.inc.php');
$loadType=$_POST['loadType'];
$loadId=$_POST['loadId'];

if($loadType=="state"){
   $sql="select id,state_name from state_test where
         country_id='".$loadId."' order by state_name asc";
}else{
   $sql="select id,city_name from city_test where
         state_id='".$loadId."' order by city_name asc";
}
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$check=mysql_num_rows($res);
if($check > 0){
   $HTML="";
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      $HTML.="<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['1']."</option>";
   }
   echo $HTML;
}
```

Comment: when you run this do you see the `image/loading.gif` i am wondering where the call is failing. The approach seems about right.

Comment: You have quite things that would make your code looks and work better, I wrote some of them in my answer and, gave you an example of how to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I think the Kendo UI dropdown widget will solve this problem. There is a cascade feature on it.

Answer (score -1):

Few thinks about your code

- With AJAX, try to use JSON to send and retrieve data, it's going to give you more freedom about vars and UI.
- As you're using jQuery, try to use it as much as possible, not defining online events, if you group them in the script it'll be easier for you to manage it.
- About the select, it's quite tricky reload them. In IE I remember I couldn't add options, so, you have to load the WHOLE select.
- Don't use PHP mysql_query functions, are quite deprecated. Read and apply this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)
- When loading values from AJAX, you have to attach the handler to the DOM elements, that's why using .on() function, to make sure it does attach the handler to the elements.
- Try to use the newer libraries of jQuery, as they are faster, powerful and have increased performance, 1.4 is pretty old...

I've written to you an example of dropdown of countries using above things, to give you a clue of how to achieve it, take what you think you like it:

**index.html:**

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('change', '#div_country select, #div_state select', function () {
            var $type = $(this).attr('data-type');
            var $id = $(this).val();

            if ( $id != -1 ) {
                loadSelect( $type, $id );
            }

        });

        function loadSelect( $type, $id ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'states.php',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    'type': $type
                ,   'id': $id
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if ( data.result == true ) {
                        if (data.html !== undefined) {
                            var $div = '';
                            if ( $type == 'country') {
                                $div = 'state';
                            } else {
                                $div = 'city';
                            }
                            $( "#div_" + $div ).html(data.html);
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Something went wrong!');
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
    </script>

    <div id="div_country">
        <select data-type="country">
            <option value="-1">Select Country</option>
            <option value="1">Spain</option>
            <option value="2">France</option>
            <option value="3">Germany</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="div_state">
        <select data-type="state">
            <option value="-1">Select Country</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="div_city">
        <select>
            <option value="-1">Select State</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**state.php**

```
<?php
$type = isset( $_POST['type'] ) ? $_POST['type'] : '';

if ( !empty( $type ) ) {
    switch ($type) {
        case 'country':
            $result = true;
            $html = '<select data-type="state">
                        <option value="-1">Select State</option>
                        <option value="1">state 1</option>
                        <option value="2">state 2</option>
                    </select>';
        break;
        case 'state':
            $result = true;
            $html = '<select data-type="city">
                        <option value="-1">Select City</option>
                        <option value="1">city 1</option>
                        <option value="2">city 2</option>
                    </select>';
        break;
        default:
            $result = false;
            $html = '';
        break;
    }
}

$data = array(
    'result' => $result,
    'html' => $html
);
```

I've added to give you a clue about how to achieve it, it's a stand alone example, and you'll see the changes of the dropbox. You'll have to add the PHP logic, but I wanted to show you a better approach, XD