# Populate HTML/PHP Dropdown Based on First Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have 1 Drop Down Which Is Used For Category (Food, Drink etc.)

In my MySQL Table (t_menu_category) I Have:

```
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------------------+
| ID | category_name | sub_category_name | category_description |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------------------+
|  1 | Food          | Curries           | Spicy Curries        |
|  2 | Food          | Meat              | Lamb, Pork, Chicken  |
|  3 | Drinks        | Alcohol           | Fine Tasting Lager   |
|  4 | Desserts      | Cakes             | Chocolate Cake       |
+----+---------------+-------------------+----------------------+
```

I have got the first dropdown showing the values of "category_name" but what I want is when I select food I want the second dropdown box to update and just show the values of "sub_category_name" where the first selection e.g. "Food" equals "Food" in the database.

So if I selected "Food" in the first dropdown box, the second dropdown box will only show "Curries" & "Meat".

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"> 
                  
    <p> 
        <label for="item_name">Item Name</label>
        <input id="item_name" name="item_name" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Item Name" />
     </p>
     <p>
        <label for="item_description">Item Description</label>
        <textarea rows="3" cols="100%" required="required" name="item_description">Item Description</textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="item_category">Item Category</label>
        <select id="item_category" name="item_category" required="required">
            <option selected="selected">-- Select Category --</option>
            <?php 
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT category_name FROM t_menu_category");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            ?>
            
            <option value="<?php echo $row['category_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></option>

            <?php
            // close while loop 
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p class="center"><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Menu Item"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: one way could be to put your PHP in a other file (web service) and call it with AJAX when a selection is done in the first select.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail as to what type of solution you're looking for?  Do you want this to happen in javascript in the browser?  Or would you like the user to submit the form, and then have the page reload with the 2nd drop down now rendered?

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728170/retrieve-data-into-ajax-dropdown-menu-using-php-mysql-jquery/22730571#22730571, it has the code to reload the dropbox depending on the sent value. In fact, as @MamaWalter says, you'll need AJAX

Comment: I want it so the second dropdown is disabled, and then when the user selects an option from the first dropdown, it's instantly enabled with the values which correspond to the first drop down.

ive seen allot of examples through out this website but can't get any to work.

Comment: i understand you can only see 1 HTML dropdown as i left that out so someone could tell me how to do it ive tried using a script which gets the id then sends it to 'ajax.php?value=Food' but nothing happens so if some could help i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create a PHP file with the request and call it with AJAX.

getSubCategory.php

```
<?php
$category = "";
if(isset($_GET['category'])){
    $category = $_GET['category'];
}

/* Connect to the database, I'm using PDO but you could use mysqli */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=my_database;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'my_user';
$password = 'my_pass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = 'SELECT sub_category_name as subCategory FROM t_menu_category WHERE category_name = :category';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':category', $category);
$stmt->execute();

return  json_encode($stmt->fetchAll());
```

and add some jquery to catch when an category is selected and ask the server for the corresponding sub-category:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#item_category').on('change', function () {

            //get selected value from category drop down
            var category = $(this).val();

            //select subcategory drop down
            var selectSubCat = $('#item_sub_category');

            if ( category != -1 ) {

                // ask server for sub-categories
                $.getJSON( "getSubCategory.php?category="+category)
                .done(function( result) {    
                    // append each sub-category to second drop down   
                    $.each(result, function(item) {
                        selectSubCat.append($("<option />").val(item.subCategory).text(item.subCategory));
                    });
                    // enable sub-category drop down
                    selectSubCat.prop('disabled', false);                
                });

            } else {                
                // disable sub-category drop down
                selectSubCat.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });    

    });
</script>
```

also add a value on your first option:

```
<option value="-1" selected="selected">-- Select Category --</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution to select states depending on a country php/javascript/mysql

MySQL tables

```
country 
      country_code varhar(5)
      country_name varchar(100)

state
      country_code varhar(5)
      state_code   varchar(5)
      country_name varchar(100)
```

Country/State selection in main.php file

```
<html>
   <body> 
     Country
            <?php
                $sql="SELECT * FROM country order by country_name";
                $rs=$conn->Execute($sql);
                echo '<select  value="'.$country_code.'"  name="country_code"  id="country_list"   onChange="stateList(this.value);" />';
                echo  '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                $rs->MoveFirst();
                while (!$rs->EOF) {
                    echo  '<option value="'.$rs->fields['country_code'].'"';
                    if  ($rs->fields['country_code'] == $country_code) {echo " selected";}
                    echo  '>'.$rs->fields['country_name'].'</option>';
                    $rs->MoveNext();
                }
                echo '</select>';
            ?>

     State
            <?php
                $sql="SELECT * FROM state where contry_code = '$country_code' order by state_name";
                $rs=$conn->Execute($sql);
                echo '<select   value="'.$state_code.'"  name="state_code" id="state_list"   />';
                echo  '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                $rs->MoveFirst();
                while (!$rs->EOF) {
                    echo  '<option value="'.$rs->fields['state_code'].'"';
                    if  ($rs->fields['state_code'] == $state_code) {echo " selected";}
                    echo  '>'.$rs->fields['state_name'].'</option>';
                    $rs->MoveNext();
                }
                echo '</select>';
            ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Java Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function stateList(val) {
   var select = document.getElementById( "state_list" );
   var url    = "get_statelist.php?country_code="+val;
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      data:'',
      success: function(data){
         $("#state_list").html(data);
      }
   });
}
```

get_stataelist.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$country_code = $_GET['country_code'];
$conn        = connect_db()  //Make your own connection entry conn with Server,DB User ID, DB Password and DB Name

if  ($country_code  !=  "") {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM state where coutry_code = '$country_code'  order by state_name";
    $rs=$conn->Execute($sql);

    echo  '<option value="">--Select--</option>';

    $rs->MoveFirst();
    while (!$rs->EOF) {
        echo  '<option value="'.$rs->fields['state_code'].'">'.$rs->fields['state_name']."</option>";
        $rs->MoveNext();
    }
}

?>
```